# Plot Non-linear Mixed Model Over Original Fitted Data

Tags: r, curve-fitting, lme4

I'm trying to plot the resultant curve from fitting a non-linear mixed model. It should be something like a curve of a normal distribution but skewed to the right. I followed previous links here and here, but when I use my data I can not make it happen for different difficulties (see below).

Here is the [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qd9g1j47tl7cpw/GRVMAX%20tadpoles.csv?dl=0)
and code

```
s=read.csv("GRVMAX tadpoles.csv") 
t=s[s$SPP== levels(s$SPP)[1],]
head(t)
vmax=t[t$PERFOR=="VMAX",]
colnames(vmax)[6]="vmax"
vmax$TEM=as.numeric(as.character(vmax$TEM));
require(lme4)
start =c(TEM=25)
is.numeric(start)
nm1 <- nlmer ( vmax ~ deriv(TEM)~TEM|INDIVIDUO,nlpars=start, nAGQ  =0,data= vmax)# this gives an error suggesting nlpars is not numeric, despite start is numeric...:~/
```

After that, I want to plot the curve over the original data

```
 with(vmax,plot(vmax ~ (TEM)))
 x=vmax$TEM
 lines(x, predict(nm1, newdata = data.frame(TEM = x, INDIVIDUO = "ACI5")))
```

Any hint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "just does not happen" look like?

Comment: quick glance, but do you want `lines` insteadf of `curve`, and does the `newdata` (not `new.data`) need to be a data.frame?

Comment: A quick note: you said you want to fit a non-linear mixed model. `lmer` is for **linear** mixed models. Also, your `x` is not a new data frame, it's a vector of the actual values. Predict only takes data frames with the same column names as the original data.

Comment: thanks, the error looks like:Error in curve(predict(m1, new.data = x), add = T) : 
  'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'lines also did not work

Comment: Maybe `x <- with(vmax, seq(min(TEM), max(TEM), length = 100)); lines(x, predict(m1, newdata = data.frame(TEM = x, INDIVIDUO = "ACI1")))`

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much. I did not understand how to construct those lines.

Comment: @Aguscamacho, if you solved your own problem, please post an answer ...

Comment: Yes, i will do when i completely solve it, still could not fit the non linear mixed model satisfactorily

Comment: @Aguscamacho; since you have edited your question, it appears as if it is not really about how to plot the results of the model, but how to actually estimate it. So could you update your question, with the parametric model that you want to fit in the main text of the question (with parametric nonlinear regression you require a predefined formula to pass to the fitting procedure). If you do not have a formula perhaps you could consider using a `gam` model with random effects (see `mgcv`)

Comment: The reason i am fitting a model is precisely to discover that curvilinear function that best fit with the original data for then plot that curve over them.

Comment: @Aguscamacho ; As it stands the equation in your model doesn't look sensible (did you look at the results of `deriv(TEM)`), and from your comment you don't seem to have a parametric form for the relationship - so if you don't have a parametric form then you should not be using parametric regression. Maybe have a look at `mgcv::gamm` to investigate / model.

Comment: looking at with (vmax,plot(vmax~TEM)) it looks like an inverted unimodal curve, but how to especify that in the  model..i dunno...